# Shopware 6.5 - Cannot generate custom document type

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I am currently trying to create a custom document type in Shopware 6.5.0.0 like described in the [Shopware docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/document/add-custom-document-type).

My custom document type gets recognized when i go to create a new document from an order in the admin, but when i try to generate the pdf - I get the error "Unable to find a document generator with type "order_confirmation"". As there is no example service created in the docs - i believe my error lies there. But i am not sure. I referenced the [invoice service renderer](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.5.0.0/src/Core/Checkout/DependencyInjection/document.xml#LL58C9-L58C80) registration for my services.xml

This is my services.xml:

```xml
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="Dima\OrderConfirmation\Core\Checkout\Document\Renderer\OrderConfirmationRenderer">
            <argument type="service" id="order.repository"/>
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Service\DocumentConfigLoader"/>
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Twig\DocumentTemplateRenderer"/>
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\System\NumberRange\ValueGenerator\NumberRangeValueGeneratorInterface"/>
            <argument>%kernel.project_dir%</argument>
            
            <tag name="document.renderer" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

And this is my document renderer:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Dima\OrderConfirmation\Core\Checkout\Document\Renderer;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Renderer\AbstractDocumentRenderer;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Renderer\DocumentRendererConfig;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Renderer\RenderedDocument;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Renderer\RendererResult;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Service\DocumentConfigLoader;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Struct\DocumentGenerateOperation;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Twig\DocumentTemplateRenderer;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\OrderEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Defaults;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Exception\DecorationPatternException;
use Shopware\Core\System\Locale\LocaleEntity;
use Shopware\Core\System\NumberRange\ValueGenerator\NumberRangeValueGeneratorInterface;

class OrderConfirmationRenderer extends AbstractDocumentRenderer
{
    public const DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = '@DimaOrderConfirmation/documents/order_confirmation.html.twig';

    final public const TYPE = 'order_confirmation';

    /**
     * @internal
     */
    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityRepository $orderRepository,
        private readonly DocumentConfigLoader $documentConfigLoader,
        private readonly DocumentTemplateRenderer $documentTemplateRenderer,
        private readonly NumberRangeValueGeneratorInterface $numberRangeValueGenerator,
        private readonly string $rootDir,
    ) {
    }

    public function supports(): string
    {
        return self::TYPE;
    }

    /**
     * @param array<DocumentGenerateOperation> $operations
     */
    public function render(array $operations, Context $context, DocumentRendererConfig $rendererConfig): RendererResult
    {
        $ids = \array_map(fn (DocumentGenerateOperation $operation) => $operation->getOrderId(), $operations);

        if (empty($ids)) {
            return new RendererResult();
        }

        $result = new RendererResult();

        $template = self::DEFAULT_TEMPLATE;

        $orders = $this->orderRepository->search(new Criteria($ids), $context)->getEntities();

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $orderId = $order->getId();

            try {
                $operation = $operations[$orderId] ?? null;
                if ($operation === null) {
                    continue;
                }

                $config = clone $this->documentConfigLoader->load(self::TYPE, $order->getSalesChannelId(), $context);

                $config->merge($operation->getConfig());

                $number = $config->getDocumentNumber() ?: $this->getNumber($context, $order, $operation);

                $now = (new \DateTime())->format(Defaults::STORAGE_DATE_TIME_FORMAT);

                $config->merge([
                    'documentDate' => $operation->getConfig()['documentDate'] ?? $now,
                    'documentNumber' => $number,
                    'custom' => [
                        'invoiceNumber' => $number,
                    ],
                ]);

                // If document is uploaded manually
                if ($operation->isStatic()) {
                    $doc = new RenderedDocument('', $number, $config->buildName(), $operation->getFileType(), $config->jsonSerialize());
                    $result->addSuccess($orderId, $doc);

                    continue;
                }

                /** @var LocaleEntity $locale */
                $locale = $order->getLanguage()->getLocale();

                $html = $this->documentTemplateRenderer->render(
                    $template,
                    [
                        'order' => $order,
                        'config' => $config,
                        'rootDir' => $this->rootDir,
                        'context' => $context,
                    ],
                    $context,
                    $order->getSalesChannelId(),
                    $order->getLanguageId(),
                    $locale->getCode()
                );

                $doc = new RenderedDocument(
                    $html,
                    $number,
                    $config->buildName(),
                    $operation->getFileType(),
                    $config->jsonSerialize(),
                );

                $result->addSuccess($orderId, $doc);
            } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
                $result->addError($orderId, $exception);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getDecorated(): AbstractDocumentRenderer
    {
        throw new DecorationPatternException(self::class);
    }

    private function getNumber(Context $context, OrderEntity $order, DocumentGenerateOperation $operation): string
    {
        return $this->numberRangeValueGenerator->getValue(
            'document_' . self::TYPE,
            $context,
            $order->getSalesChannelId(),
            $operation->isPreview()
        );
    }
}
```

I confirmed that the TYPE const matches with the document type i create in my migration, as i first thought that there maybe was a typo - but to no success.

What is it that i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That all looks to be correct. Did you implement the `supports` method like this?

```php
public function supports(): string
{
    return self::TYPE;
}
```

[This is the only line](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/baca2e7d2e1c004a51d351ad92250980b963b35c/src/Core/Checkout/Document/Renderer/DocumentRendererRegistry.php#L31) where this exception is thrown. And it only happens if it iterates all the `document.renderer` tagged services without evaluating one that supports the type.

It looks like your service is not being registered at all if it's not matching up. Do you have other services in your `services.xml` that you can confirm being registered, so you can say for sure you didn't misplace the file or something like that?

Comment: I indeed have the `supports` method like you described in your answer.

That is currently the only service in my `services.xml`.

The path to my `services.xml` is : `src/Resources/config/services.xml` - I also have a `plugin.png` in the same folder that does get loaded

Comment: I seem to have resolved the issue - The plugin was deactivated, even though i specifically activated it before.. Now the service works